# Rule for BOGOGO(Buy 1 get 1 same product free) in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules

How to create a **rule** in **Magento 2** for **BOGOGO**(Buy 1 get 1 same product free and give another product)?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a **buy x Get y free** on Magento:

1st. Go to `Marketing > Cart prices rules`

2nd. Click on Add new rule

3rd. Define a name, a short descritpion, select website and customer groups

4th. Define if your promotion require a coupon to be activated or not

5th. Define a period

6th. **Conditions** : nothing to set up here

7th. **ACTIONS** :

- Select "Buy x Get Y free"
- Discount amount put "1" (that means 1 prodcut free)
- Maximum qty discount apply : Select how many times in the order this promotions can be applied
- Discount qty : Put "1" for a Buy 1 get 1 Free or put "1" to apply a buy 1 get 1 free

8th. Rule to apply to cart items : clik on SKU and type the sku of the product concerned by this promotion.

So basically, if you have set up a Buy 1 get 1 free promotion for example, you customer my need to add 2 products in his cart, then he'll get a 100% on one of these products.

## For more information [visit](https://www.customerparadigm.com/cart-price-rules-magento/)